# Eclipse(or intellij) function parameter usage static analysis

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin, intellij-plugin

Consider a java code like following

```
class Myobject{
public:
    int f0();
    int f1();
    void setSth(String result);
    ..etc...
};
....
class executor{

    void execute(Myobject /* want to analyse this */input){
        int tmp = input.f0();
        calc(input);
    }
    void calc(Myobject input) {
        ... calc ...
        input.setSth("Done"); 
    }
}
```

Is there a tool/plugin in intellij/eclipse that could give me the usage of the paramter **input** within the call graph of execute function? Something will give me result like **f0()** and **setSth(..)** function are called under **execute()** but not **f1()**.

Comment: how is this under "java"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your expected result is. But in IntelliJ you can right click on a variable and select `Analyze data flow from/to here`.

For example here is some code where I've clicked: `Analyze data flow from here`:
[image: Dataflow analysis]

Comment: This would work if it can group the usage by function call. i.e. all usage of addRuleset would be grouped. Also why export to text doesn't export the whole output(some are omitted by "...").

Comment: That is not possible in one overview as far as I know. You could "analyse dataflow to here" (instead of "from here"). But that would require another analysis. With regard to the (broken?) output... perhaps thats an issue. Feel free to report issues on their issue tracker here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissues%2FIDEA